# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL setting vars

Tags: javascript, token

Here is a snippet of code

```
var Loop = setInterval(function(){
        for (var Id in hats) {
                var origLink = "http://www.roblox.com/x-item?id=" + hats[Id]
                $.get(origLink,function(data){
                        var Regex = item\Dprivatesale\Dprice\D\D([\d])\D\Dspan\D
```

I have used a lot of \D's as that is where non-letter characters are and I don't want to risk escaping the wrong ones.

Why am I getting this error? Which tokens are illegal? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex need to be surrounded by /, so your Regex will be:

```
var Regex = /item\Dprivatesale\Dprice\D\D([\d])\D\Dspan\D/;
```

Or using the RegExp class, like:

```
var regex = new RegExp("item\Dprivatesale\Dprice\D\D([\d])\D\Dspan\D");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm now getting a different error, I will make a new question about this one!

Comment: You're welcome, if I helped you, please mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: Sure thing, the whole code isn't working properly. It's not too much longer than this, about 2.5x the size of what I originally gave, is it possible for you to add me on Skype or something and help me out with the rest?